# How to push newly added or updated domain values to ArcGIS rest service?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, rest, feature-service

I'm currently using ArcGIS Server 10.4 for my REST service and ArcGIS Online. I have created a domain list and assigned it to a field. All of it works fine. I'm currently using Oracle for my geodatabase. When i added the the rest service to a webmap, i can see the domains as a select list.

However, from time to time, additional values must be added to the domain or need to be updated. I tried updating it in ArcMap and it reflects nicely. In editing mode you can see it straightaway in the select list. This is not the same for the REST service. After adding in the value, it is still not available when i try to check it via webmap.

I then proceed to restart the REST service and now it starts to show the new entries. Is this the standard way? in order for it to reflect the new entries, i would constantly need to restart the service?

Is there a way to refresh the connection to the geodatabase maybe without the need of fully restarting a rest service. I can see that if you add/or edit data in ArcMap and save editing, it can straightaway reflect. But this is not the case for domain.

Is there a way around restarting the service?

Comment: Domain changes are fundamental modifications. You're lucky you don't need to stop the service before modifying the domain, and then republish the service. There is no way for Server to detect domain change and refresh the service without restart.

Comment: I think by default map services refresh at midnight so the changes should be picked up automatically then.

Comment: overwrite the existing the existing service the new service being written will pick up the domain changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the service is published, there's a [schema lock](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/geodatabase-locks.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_1CE372453DCB4D5B9C2F6CF31CCB4057) established on the item. The [domain is part of this schema](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/working-with-schema-changes.htm). You might be able to kill the lock but the service will not show the changes until you restart.